# Sensenet: Define Content Type with File Upload

Tags: sensenet

How Can I define an content type with a field that contains an file? I think I should use binary type data to do it that but I don't know how to do the rest... 
This [example](http://wiki.sensenet.com/How_to_create_a_Content_Type#3._Insert_Content_Type_Definition_XML_and_click_Install) uses image upload, but I'm don't know how to define a field as a simple file upload...

Answer (score 4):

The "File" content type is designed to upload any kind of file. In the example - what you said - described a specialized content type with image related metadata. You should try to use the File content type. If its metadata is not good enough for you, you can create an inherited content type with the desired field set.

Answer (score 2):

As Zoltan has written in sensenet there is a predefined content type called `File` to handle any kind of file you want. If you inherit your custom CTD from this type (`parentType="File"`) it will automatically have a Binary field to store file's binary data when upload and you can define additional fields for custom metas.

If you want to use a content type inherited differently you can use a Binary field to store any kind of data, but will lose built in upload functionality (`Upload page`). In the other hand on the New/Edit page there will be the File upload's `Browse` button beside your custom field.

With this it's important to set properly the visibility configurations. If it's set to `Hide` then you won't be able to upload a file from the New or Edit page.

```
<Field name="CustomField" type="Binary">
  <DisplayName>Custom Field</DisplayName>
  <Configuration>
    <VisibleBrowse>Hide</VisibleBrowse>
    <VisibleEdit>Show</VisibleEdit>
    <VisibleNew>Show</VisibleNew>
  </Configuration>
</Field>
```